# iOS9 Text notification feature, I get nil value in responseInfo in app delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to update my app with new "text reply" action added in iOS9.
I updated my code as per instruction in WWDC15 videos/documents and http://fancypixel.github.io/blog/2015/06/11/ios9-notifications-and-text-input/.

I am able to get reply button and text box in my notification on IOS9 beta 5. After typing the message the app delegate

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(nullable NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo withResponseInfo:(NSDictionary *)responseInfo completionHandler:(void(^)())completionHandler{
```

i implemented also gets called. But "responseInfo" is coming null and i am unable to get the text.The "identifier" clearly shows "TEXT_ACTION". "category" in user info shows as 'reply'. The only piece missing is "responseInfo". Am i missing some more setting in order to receive the text i typed.

Comment: When i explicitly make "textAction.activationMode = .Background". It started working it does not work with "textAction.activationMode = .Foreground".

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem as you when I was on iOS 9.0, even though it had previously worked on iOS 9.0. I thought maybe updating to iOS 9.1 would fix it along with the update to XCode, but on the first push it the problem persisted. I kept continuing to send push notifications and reimplemented the delegate method with just a NSLog and it started working again. So I'm not really sure what fixed it.

Comment: I tried on iOS 9.1 and tried to send notification many times.But didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting activationMode to background?

```
action.activationMode = .Background
action.activationMode.behavior = .TextInput
```